# Apps limit for beta version release in itunesconnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

How many application I can release for beta version release in iTunesConnect?

Can anyone tell me the count?

Comment: Do you mean how many devices can install one particular beta or how many concurrent betas you can run?

Comment: Alex Wulff, No, I want to know, How many beta version's I can create?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limit for uploading an app, but you can put only one build of each application under review. Let's say you have 4 app in your account and you want to upload build to review, you can send one build for each app.

Comment: Thanks @Sharad Paghadal for reply.